# How can I separate access logs from requests of two different domains of the same server?

Tags: nginx

My nginx configuration looks like this:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name domain1.com domain2.com;

   access_log /var/log/myapp/nginx/access.log;

   ...
}
```

Currently requests from both domains are logged into the same file, I want to separate these so that requests from `domain1.com` continue to be saved in `access.log`, while requests from `domain2.com` be saved in `domain2.access.log`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Why not just use 2 server blocks.

Comment: @AD7six They are currently exactly the same. The difference is that one of them is used by our partners for invoking some of our APIs.

Comment: You haven't said anything which changes the question. put "exactly the same" in a file and include it in both config blocks, for example.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a variable in your `access_log` entry. For instance:

```
access_log /var/log/nginx/$http_host-access.log
```

Comment: Thanks. But if I have set my `server_name` to be `domain1.com www.domain1.com domain2.com www.domain2.com`, will this config results in four log files instead of two?

Comment: I'm trying to keep requests from `domain1` to be logged in `access.log` without any prefix. Should I set a new variable like `log_prefix`, and use it in `access_log` like `/$log_prefixaccess.log`?